# display json that is in a array

Tags: html, arrays, json, ionic-framework

looking to display title values from json file. but in the HTML it can only dig down to an array and displays object: object. I'm looking to find the title which is located under sections.0.foreground.title.  do I need to add something to my home.ts or can it all be in the HTML? thanks
[cannot read property'0" of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp9tw.png)

[new html error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npGJ8.png)

[image: object object, object object error]

[image: json values]

Home.html

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="storymap" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <ion-item>
         <ion-label color="primary">URL</ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Storymap URL" formControlName="storymapurl" [(ngModel)]="inputName"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item> *ngFor="let item of result.values.sections">
     <button ion-button (click) = "getData()">Get Data</button>
     <ion-row>Title:{{item.foreground.title}}</ion-row>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label>storymap</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
     <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
   </ion-item>
   <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!storymap.valid">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

home.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
 import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import $ from 'jquery'


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })

export class HomePage {

  private storymap : FormGroup;

   result:any= [];
   data: Observable<any>;
   public  inputName: string;

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http:HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     this.storymap = this.formBuilder.group({
       storymapurl: [''],
       title: ['', Validators.required],
       description: [''],
    });
  }


  getData(){
     this.inputName;
     console.log('here', this.inputName)
     this.data = this.http.get(this.inputName);
     this.data.subscribe(data => {
     this.result = data;
      // console.log(data)
     this.title = data.sections[0].foreground.title
     console.log(this.title)
    });
 }



 logForm(){


    console.log(this.storymap.value)
 }

}
```

Comment: You need to div into js a little bit. Display json:`{{result.values.sections | json }}` https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe . Display title: `getData` `this.title = data.sections[0].foreground.title` and then into template `{{title}}`, add to class property title:string

Comment: @MaksimRomanenko it gives an error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after our convo I think I understood your use case:
* user clicks Button getData()
* users sees data's title for the first item in sections?

Then you need to do:

```
<form [formGroup]="storymap" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <ion-item>
         <ion-label color="primary">URL</ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Storymap URL" formControlName="storymapurl" [(ngModel)]="inputName"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
     <button ion-button (click) = "getData()">Get Data</button>
     <ion-row>Title:{{title}}</ion-row>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label>storymap</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
     <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
   </ion-item>
   <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!storymap.valid">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

And in your ts file:

```
    export class HomePage {

       private storymap : FormGroup;
  private title: string;
  private inputName: string = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b9ec967ce39a49cd8de6fd24aa14d477/data?f=json"
  private result: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http:HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.storymap = this.formBuilder.group({
       storymapurl: [''],
       title: ['', Validators.required],
       description: [''],
    });
  }

  getData(){
     this.http.get(this.inputName).subscribe(data => {
         this.result = data;
         this.title = this.result.values.sections[0].foreground.title;
         console.log(this.result.values.sections[0].foreground.title)
    });
 }
```

If this still produces error - please console log what you get in response above.

Here is working blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yuvxgm

Comment: ' getData(){
         this.inputName;
         console.log('here', this.inputName)
         this.data = this.http.get(this.inputName);
         this.data.subscribe(data => {
         this.result = data;
          // console.log(data)
         this.title = data.sections[0].foreground.title
        console.log(this.title)
        });
     } '    @SergeyRudenko  I still get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'foreground' of undefined

Comment: Hey sorry, can you explain what getData method is expected to do?

Comment: it get's the inputname which is typed in the url textbox and gets the json from that link

Comment: i'll change my code with the main question to what I have currently.

Comment: OK so the UX you need is: user enters URL, needs to get just 1 title in return? can you clarify this? are you looking to get just first result?

Comment: yes I am just looking for the 1st title that is in the json.

Comment: Ops then I will update my answer in a bit with proper one;)

Comment: I still get a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: also the html isn't showing up correctly now.  I added the pictures above

Comment: OK I created this in stackblitz. See the link in updated answer.